# JS cross domain

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-browser

I want to refresh a parent page from a child `iframe` by clicking on save button.
The iframe is in a different domain to the parent page, and I get this error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL
>   'https://rapl--feature1.cs17.my.salesforce.com/canvas/proxy.jsp?a=%7B%22...clientWidt%22%7D&v=35.0'
>
> from frame with URL
>   'https://salesforceiii.com/ManageAccountSubscription.aspx'.
>
> The frame attempting navigation is neither same-origin with the target, nor is
>   it the target's parent or opener.

Can anyone guide me how to fix that , thanks in advance

Comment: Do you control the code in both windows ... iframe and parent?

Comment: You can fix it if and only if you can edit the code of *both* the parent and the child.  If one of the pages is out of your control, then this cannot be done.  It's for security.

Comment: No just in the iframe . the parent is out sourcing

Comment: If you cannot edit the code on the parent (or ask whomever owns it to do so) then you cannot do this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @Microfed postMessage won't help without being able to control parent code

Comment: @charlietfl Yep, you're totally right.